# Problem with styling an select option tag, dropdown items with icon

Tags: html, css

I have below code and i have two problems:

1. The icons only display on Firefox, I want some cross-browser thing
2. Selected item has no icon, but when we expand the list all menus contains icon

** HTML

```
<select name="im_type" id="imtype">
    <option value="Yahoo">Yahoo</option>
    <option value="MSN">MSN</option>
    <option value="GTalk">GTalk</option>
    <option value="ICQ">ICQ</option>
    <option value="AOL">AOL</option>
    <option value="Skype">Skype</option>
</select>
```

** CSS

```
select#imtype option {
    padding: 2px 0 2px 25px;
}
select#imtype option[value="Yahoo"] {
    background: url('../images/yahoo.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}
select#imtype option[value="MSN"] {
    background: url('../images/msn.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}
select#imtype option[value="GTalk"] {
    background: url('../images/gtalk.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}
select#imtype option[value="ICQ"] {
    background: url('../images/icq.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}
select#imtype option[value="AOL"] {
    background: url('../images/aol.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}
select#imtype option[value="Skype"] {
    background: url('../images/skype.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

If you have any idea, please share with me, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using this jquery plugin:

http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/jquery-image-dropdown/index.html